# debezium kafka connect issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to connect kafka-connect to remote AWS MSK kafka CLUSTERS. i have 3 brokers and 3 zookeepers with AWS.
My kafka-connect machine is a standalone machine.
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/standalone-worker.properties config/standalone-connect.properties that is how i run.

it times out with an error "Timed out waiting for a node assignment."

my standalone-worker.properties is

```
bootstrap.servers=my3 brokers add
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
client.id=mymachine
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
sasl.jaas.config= \
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="mytest" \
    password="myremotebrokerpassword";
plugin.path=/opt/kafka-connectors
```

standalone-connect.properties is empty at the moment.

Is there anyone who can give me a clue?

I wanted to use debezium send all my mysql updates to remote kafka.

Comment: If your other property file is empty, then no connectors are going to run. In any case, sounds like a networking issue... do the console producer and consumer work with those similar properties?

Comment: i have added connector information in the standalone-connect.properties. The strange thing is, when i restart the kafka-connect i can see the schema records in the kafka but nothing after that. if i update anything in the database i see it tries to commit but failed.